# How to insert an array of terms using wp_insert_term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

WP provides a function to insert terms:

```
<?php wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() ); ?>
```

I have 60 $terms, each has its own $args, I want to prepare the 60 terms as an array, then, insert them at once. Is this posible? How?

Comment: This is a great question and probably a lack in wordpress API. Considering more than 600 terms the insertions are really slow !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the [codex for wp_insert_term says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term#Parameters), it is not possible to insert an array directly. Put all your terms in an array, then foreach over it and inside every turn, call `wp_insert_term` once per term.